# R: Unfair Coin Toss with Monte Carlo Method. Goal is Probability of N Exact Heads

Tags: r, montecarlo

I have a task to use the Monte Carlo  method to evaluate an unfair coin flip and determine the probability of obtaining n heads out of n flips within n simulations. The guide my professor provided (at bottom) isn't making sense for how to adjust it for an unfair coin. I've included what I started coding, but it's nowhere near complete. How can I adjust Monte Carlo to work for an unfair coin?

Problem:

Assume you have a coin that is not fair, where the probability of having a heads is p. We are interested in the probability of seeing exactly nheads heads out of a total of nflips flips. Write a function that takes these arguments to evaluate this probability over nsim simulations (a total of four arguments), and test it out on a few different values. Hint: use the prob argument in the sample function.

```
nsim <- 10000
nheads <-
nflips <- 
p <- NULL
unfairfunc <- function(x){
  for(nheads in 1:nsim)
  nheads <-
  nflips <-
    }
```

Below is the base code my professor provided for Monte Carlo probabilities for a fair coin toss.

```
 flip_function <- function(n) {
  flips <- sample(c("heads", "tails"), n, replace=TRUE) 
  percent_heads <- length(which(flips== "heads")) / n
  return(percent_heads)
}
```

Comment: The professors' code is straight forward. just include `prob = c(p, 1-p)` in the sample function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sample` function has `prob` argument, which can be used to assign a probability weight value for each possible outcome. If none is assigned to `prob`, the `sample` function will take simple random sampling in which each possible outcome has the same probability weight, so each will have the same probability to be selected, which is a *fair* condition.

For example:

```
# Case 1:
sample(c("a", "b"), 1) 

#Case 2:
sample(c("a", "b"), 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.8))
```

In Case #1, the probability of "a" being sampled equals the probability of "b" being sampled, which is 1/2 = 50%.

In Case #2, the probability of "a" being sampled is 20%, but the probability of "b" being sampled is 80%.

If you repeat the sample function N times, it can be expected that "a" will be selected about 50% N times in Case #1, and about 20% N times in Case #2.

Try many times:

```
Case #1 
s <- numeric(10)
for(k in 1:10) s[k] <- sample(c("a", "b"), 1)
table(s)

Case #2 
s <- numeric(10)
for(k in 1:10) s[k] <- sample(c("a", "b"), 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.8))
table(s)
```

Note that :

- if `prob` is to be set, a weight value must be assigned to each possible outcome, and
- the sum of the weights assigned to `prob` must equal 1.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, Abdur Rohman! I appreciate it!

Comment: @shesmartsometimes If this answer solves your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark next to the answer. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved and it gives the person that helps you credit. This is completely optional!